# howto use batch Read text file export to output file

Tags: batch-file

i have text file format

```
2013-08-13 17:12:39 3868 0 status: Starting upload of U:\AOT\KPT_BU\

2013-08-13 17:12:39 3868 0 status: Starting upload of U:\AOT\KPT_BU\

2013-09-13 17:12:39 3868 0 status: Starting upload of U:\AOT\KPT_BU\

2013-09-13 17:12:39 3868 0 status: Starting upload of U:\AOT\KPT_BU\

2013-08-13 17:12:39 3868 0 status: Starting upload of U:\AOT\KPS\

2013-08-13 17:12:39 3868 0 status: Starting upload of U:\AOT\KPS\

2013-08-13 17:12:39 3868 0 status: Starting upload of U:\AOT\KPS\

2013-09-13 17:12:39 3868 0 status: Starting upload of U:\AOT\KPS\

2013-09-13 17:12:39 3868 0 status: Starting upload of U:\AOT\KPS\

2013-09-13 17:12:39 3868 0 status: Starting upload of U:\AOT\KPS\

2013-09-13 17:12:39 3868 0 status: Starting upload of U:\AOT\KPS\
```

i want Output file Format

```
date 2013-08-13 KPT_BU total = 2

date 2013-08-13 KPS Total = 3

date 2013-09-13 KPT_BU total = 2

date 2013-09-13 KPS total = 4
```

Comment: What is the scope of your file?  How many days and months will be in the log?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I assume that you want to achieve the following:
You want to count the uploads to the specified folders for each date.

My solution creates an environment variable for each date and path-name combination and puts a counter into that variable. It heavy relies on ENABLEDELAYEDEXPANSION and I cannot think of a solution without that, because you cannot use the alternative call/%% in the 'for' construct.
If anyone know a solution to this I would be quite happy to get to know this.
So this solution will not work with paths which contain '!'. As the script relies on creating environment variables, it will stop when you run out of environment memory.

```
@echo off
setlocal ENABLEDELAYEDEXPANSION
:: remove all variabel starting with $ they will be restored after 'endlocal'
for /f "tokens=1 delims==" %%# in ('set $') do set "%%#="
:: create an environment variable from the date and path and increase its
:: value for every match
for /f "delims=" %%# in (testfile.txt) do (
    :: get first and last token ($1=date and $2=path) from line
    set "$1="
    for %%A in (%%#) do set $1>nul 2>nul||set "$1=%%A" & set "$2=%%A"
    :: get last part of path from $2 (mask '\' with '" "' to use in for
    set "$2="!$2:\=" "!
    for %%A in (!$2!) do set $2=%%~A
    :: generate envvar '-' must be removed, because set/a gets confused by '-'
    set "_=$!$1:-=!!$2!"
    :: counting in created vars
    if defined !_! ( set /a "!_!+=1" ) else ( set "!_!=1" ) 
)
set "$1=" & set "$2="
::output results
for /f "tokens=1,2 delims==" %%A in ('set $ 2^>nul') do (
    set _=%%A
    echo date !_:~1,4!-!_:~5,2!-!_:~7,2! !_:~8! Total = %%B
)
endlocal
goto:eof
```

The output is slightly different because 'set $' sorts the variables alphabetically.

Comment: very Excellent,and thank you so much for reply. It very close to complete, Yes i want to count file upload by date in log filezilla

Answer (score 0):

Output file when i run bat file

++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++
date 2013-09-11 1 Total = 736 ----> Not Use

date 2013-09-11 111092013_66file_B Total = 64

date 2013-09-11 1KPDC Total = 1

date 2013-09-11 1KPT Total = 1

date 2013-09-11 1KPT_BU Total = 7

date ﻿2-01-30 0911 Total = 1

++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++

i have full log file

http://www.4shared.com/file/eax2ykoS/filezilla.html

Thank you..